# Is there a standard or recommended sound lib in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, application-development

Sound is kind of fractured in the Linux world. There is [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page), [Open Sound](http://www.opensound.com/), [PulseAudio](http://www.pulseaudio.org/), [OpenAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx) ...

Is there one "favoured" or "standard" or "recommended" lib to use in sound-emitting software in Ubuntu? (I'm particularly interested in videogames)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fractured Linux audio landscape is basically a myth nowadays. All sound technologies on Ubuntu that have not been deprecated or dead for six years are complementary. To paraphrase [Lennart Poettering](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/guide-to-sound-apis.html) with slight updates and an Ubuntu app-developer perspective:

> #### I want to write a media-player-like application!
>
> > Use [GStreamer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/ubuntu-developer-stack/multimedia/)!
>
> #### I want to add event sounds to my application!
>
> > Use [libcanberra](http://developer.gnome.org/libcanberra/unstable/index.html), install your sound files according to the [XDG Sound Theming/Naming Specifications](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/sound-theme-spec)!
>
> #### I want to add sound to my game!
>
> > Use the audio API of [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) for full-screen games, [libcanberra](http://developer.gnome.org/libcanberra/unstable/index.html) for simple games with standard UIs such as Gtk+.